# Regular expression split string

Tags: regex

I'm looking to split a string (and get all the matches) using a regular expression.

I have the following string:

```
ppc.goo.gen.heat..jan-17.logo
```

It should return everything between each .

```
[0] ppc
[1] goo
[2] gen
[3] heat
[4] 
[5] jan-17
[6] logo
```

So far I have this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.
```

Which matches 0 to 5, but it'll miss off match 6 as it doesn't have a . at the end. I tried using lookahead but I couldn't get it working. Any tips?

Comment: What is the environment/too/programming language? Why not split with `.`?

Comment: It's not in a programming language - it's a web based tool where I only have the ability to run a regular expression. I don't have the ability to run any split functions

Comment: So, is it JavaScript regex then?

Comment: I didn't say as I don't really know. It's a web based tool and I don't know if it runs the regular expression server side or client side.

Comment: It is easy to check. Try `[^.]+|(?<=^|\.)(?=\.|$)`

Comment: It's some internal enterprise software - I don't even know the name of it. Unfortunately I've just been asked by a colleague to help them with the regex!

Comment: Ah. So do you actually need that empty entry? If not this would be really simple.

Comment: Unfortunately yes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`(?:^|\.)([^\.]*)(?=\.|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/re9Bjp/2)

Group 1 will be the entry.

- `(?:^|\.)` Match start of string, or `.`
- `([^\.]*)` Match 0 or more non-`.` characters
- `(?=\.|$)` Match `.` or end of string